# accessing data in php object

Tags: php, object

```
Iyzipay\Model\ThreedsInitialize Object ( [htmlContent:Iyzipay\Model\ThreedsInitialize:private] => [status:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => failure [errorCode:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => 5251 [errorMessage:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => Banka kartları için taksit yapılamaz [errorGroup:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => [locale:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => tr [systemTime:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => 1628696035608 [conversationId:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => 123456789 [rawResult:Iyzipay\ApiResource:private] => {"status":"failure","errorCode":"5251","errorMessage":" Banka kartları için taksit yapılamaz","locale":"tr","systemTime":1628696035608,"conversationId":"123456789"} )
```

how can i access 'errorMessage' in this object

Comment: Can you share the code inside ThreedsInitialize class?

Comment: ThreedsInitialize doesn't have any code. this data comes from another site

Comment: Then try `$obj->getErrorMessage()`. Note that this is just a wild guess. Seeing the code would be best. You can't access private properties directly. You will need to use a getter method to fetch them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but Assuming the output you provided is string that comes from requesting another data source; You can use JSON field extraction regex like this. Note that `$responseString` is the response body like the one you had in question.

```php
$re = '/"errorMessage":"((\\\\"|[^"])*)"/i';

preg_match($re, $responseString, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

$errorMessage = $matches[1][0];

var_dump($errorMessage);
```

For example for the provided response in question the result would be:

```
string(40) " Banka kartları için taksit yapılamaz"
```

**BE AWARE** In case if there was no matching for regex it will throw `Undefined offset`.